# Обработка строк из файла в Python

Tags: python

Возникла следующая проблема. Никак не могу разобраться, как обработать строки из файла.
Есть csv файл, в котором лежат тысячи строк по типу:

```
ab
abc abcd ab
abcdef abc abc ab
```

Возможно я с самого начала выбрал не верный путь. Поправьте, если есть путь проще.
Я считываю весь файл в dataframe pandas с помощью:

```
data = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], sep=',').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Далее использую это, чтобы отбросить хедеры столбцов в dataframe и индексы:

```
temp = data.to_csv(header=None, index=False).strip('\n').split('\n')
```

Теперь, при обращение к temp[0] я получаю первую строку, temp[1] вторую и т.д.
Моя цель: пройти весь файл и оставить только те строки, которые удовлетворяют определенным условиям (например, первое слово больше трех символов).
Я никак не могу составить циклы для сканирования строк. В каком-нибудь C++ я бы указал в качестве триггера окончания вложенного цикла символ конца строки ('\n'). Так я и попытался сделать тут, но там как-будто нет этого символа и после последней буквы слова он сообщает мне, что я вышел за рамки строки. Вот мой ошибочный код:

```
for i in range(0, 30):
    while temp[i][j] != "\n":
        if temp[i][j] == ' ' and j > 2:
            print(temp[i])
            j+=1
            break
        else:
            j+=1
            continue
    j = 0
```

Как мне решить мою проблему? Как при посимвольном сканирование строчки зафиксировать, что мы достигли конца строки и надо переходить к следующей?

Comment: Подождите. У вас в файле строки, а вы читаете поля разделенные ",". Уточните, что содержится в файле. Если только строки, то это не csv.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU извиняюсь, если не совсем точно изложил суть вопроса, но проблема крылась в отсутствие понимания тонкостей работы Python. Ответ ниже полностью решил проблему. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как можно решить вашу задачу. Так как у вас просто строки, то pandas не нужен совсем.

```
def checkLine(line):
    #в строке есть слово длиннее трех символов
    words=line.split()
    for word in words:
        if len(word)>3:
            return True
    return False

filer = open("in.txt","r")
outfile=open("out.txt","w")
for line in filer:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if checkLine(line)==True:
        outfile.write(line+"\n")

filer.close()
outfile.close()
```

Можно переписать функцию checkLine для реализации желаемого поведения.